# $\gamma: R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism and $I \lhd R$, want an example of when $\gamma(I) \ntriangleleft S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I just proved that if $\gamma: R \rightarrow S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and $I \lhd R$ then $\gamma(I) \lhd S$. I'm now looking for an example of where this fails if $\gamma$ is not surjective. I've been looking for one for awhile but alas, i have not come up with anyone. Looking for a new perspective, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What examples of non-surjective ring homomorphisms have you tried?  Assuming you are working with unital rings, literally every non-surjective ring homomorphism is a counterexample.

Comment: Hm, okay. I just tried $R \leq S$, so $R$ is a subring of $S$ and then used the inclusion mapping. I'm trying to find a contradiction, but thus far have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the inclusion of a domain that is not a field into its field of fractions.